# Annotation turn to it's default state in iOS 9

Tags: iphone, swift, mkmapview, ios9, mkannotation

In iOS 9 map annotation is showing up as black pin for current location and other as red pin. My custom assets are missing and also on tap my custom callout view is not showing up. I am not sure what happening. Same code is running in iOS 8 and everything work as expected. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: Down voter hope you know the answer, can you help me?

Comment: Its really frustrating, I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to subclass your annotation view from `MKAnnotationView`, not from `MKPinAnnotationView`. I had the same issue and I solved my problem with this.